# Javascript: follow cursor but stay within a circle as opposed to rectangle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the jsfiddle sample below to make the yellow circle div *follow the mouse* **but be constraint to a circle** as opposed to a square (div).

http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/

The JS code looks like so:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$(window).mousemove(function(e){
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY, limitY);
});

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});

}, 30);
```

I understand the structure and methodology of the code, just not too familiar with the syntax!

Where is the best place to update the `limitX/Y` and throw in the extra `radius`, `distance` variables?

Comment: something like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/211/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by computing the distance away from the center of the circle (2D distances are computed with [`Math.sqrt`](http://www.javascripture.com/Math#sqrt)`(x * x + y * y)`).  Then check to see if the distance is greater than the radius of the circle you'd like to constrain to.  If it is, scale down the distance to match your constraining radius.

Here's the snippet:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
var centerX = limitX / 2, centerY = limitY / 2;
var radius = centerX;
$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
   var diffX = e.pageX - centerX;
   var diffY = e.pageY - centerY;

   // Get the mouse distance from the center
   var r = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

   if (r > radius) {
     // Scale the distance down to length 1 
     diffX /= r;
     diffY /= r;

     // Scale back up to the radius
     diffX *= radius;
     diffY *= radius;
   }

   mouseX = centerX + diffX;
   mouseY = centerY + diffY;
});
```

And here's the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/fhmkf/